# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') Getting error while connecting to sockjs

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm getting the above error when trying to run the application. I'm using spring boot on the backend and websocket. And using js and sockjs library.
This is the error I'm getting:

```
ChatRoom.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')<br/>
at ChatRoom (ChatRoom.js:45:1)<br/>
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)<br/>
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)<br/>
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)<br/>
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)<br/>
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)<br/>
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)<br/>
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)<br/>
at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26085:1)<br/>
at flushSyncCallbacks (react-dom.development.js:12042:1)<br/>



abstract-xhr.js:132     GET https://localhost:8282/NotificationService/info?t=1695387828667 <br/>
net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Everything is working fine if instead of creating a separate file for the frontend code I put all the code in the spring boot project itself.

This is the component/chatRoom.js file

```
const ChatRoom = () => {

    let socket = new SockJS("https://localhost:8282/NotificationService");

    let stompClient = over(socket);

    stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
        console.log('WebSocket connection established.');

        stompClient.subscribe('/notification/message', (message) => {
            const notification = JSON.parse(message.body);
            displayMessage(notification);
        });
    });

    function sendMessage() {
        const messageInput = document.getElementById('messageInput');
        const message = messageInput.value.trim();

        if (message) {
            const notification = {
                messageContent: message,
                messageRecipient: '', // Set the recipient if required
                status: '',
                createdDate: new Date().toISOString(),
            };

            stompClient.send('/app/sendMessage', {}, JSON.stringify(notification));
            messageInput.value = '';
        }
    }

    function displayMessage(notification) {
        const messageList = document.getElementById('messageList');
        const messageElement = document.createElement('li');
        messageElement.textContent = notification.messageContent;
        messageList.appendChild(messageElement);
    }

    document.getElementById('sendButton').addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
    document.getElementById('messageInput').addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });

    return (
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>WebSocket Chat</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Received Messages</h1>
                <ul id="messageList">
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <label for="messageInput"></label><input type="text" id="messageInput" placeholder="Type your message..." />
                    <button id="sendButton">Send</button>
                </div>

            </body>
        </html>
    )
}


export default ChatRoom
```

This is the app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ChatRoom from './component/ChatRoom';

function App() {
  return (
   <ChatRoom />
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```